# Quickest way to filter a list of words

Tags: c#, list, filter

I have a list with several words. I want to filter out some of them, which don't match a specific pattern. Is it quicker to add all the matches to a temporary list and copy this list to the main list afterwards? Or is it quicker to remove all the mismatches from the main list?
I have to filter 10000 words as quickly as possible, so I'm looking forward to every little speed increasement.

Edit:

```
string characters = "aAbBcC";
// currentMatches contains all the words from the beginning
List<string> currentMatches = new List<string>();
List<string> newMatches = new List<string>();
foreach (string word in currentMatches)
{
   if (characters.IndexOf(word[0]) > -1)
   // word match
   {
       newMatches.Add(word);
   }
}
currentMatches = newMatches;
```

The `foreach` loop should check whether `word` begins with one of the characters of `characters`. Here I copy every match to `newMatches` before I copy all the new matches to `currentMatches`.

Comment: No. It just has to be very fast and I don't know what happens inside my CPU. So I don't know what's quicker.

Comment: Maybe you should just try a few methods - I'd suggest Linq, since it's pretty quick - something like yourList.Where(x => x == someFilterExpression). Are you optimising something - do you have something that's already slow that you are trying to optimise? What's the actual reason for needing it to be lightning fast?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: 10000 words is not that much. I doubt you will get significant improvements with any method.

Comment: @Tudor is right. Just to give you some perspective, if you had a Dictionary<string,object> containing 10,000 entries, it takes less than 100 milliseconds to do 1,000,000 TryGet lookups on that Dictionary running in my nothing-special laptop.

Comment: @JamesHill: Nice pun (and solution) ;p

Comment: This smells like premature optimization. Surely that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) then you'll have to take in consideration the following:

- If Count is less than Capacity, the [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) method is an O(1) operation. If the capacity needs to be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count;
- The [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) method is an O(n) operation, where n is (Count - index).

If you create the list to hold the matches with an initial capacity set to the total word count then `Add` will always be O(1) and faster. However you need to take in consideration the overhead of creating this new list with a capacity set to the total word count.

Bottom line, you need to test it and see what works better for your specific scenario.

Comment: Last line: spoken like a true politician :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I threw together on how to time methods. There are many ways to do this, and I think you're going to have to try out a few. You can use information like in João Angelo's post to help direct you towards good approaches, but here are a few. Also, if you're willing to spend the time, you could put this all in a loop that would create a new list, run all of the tests, put the TimeSpan results into a collection instead of Console.WriteLine'ing them, and then give you an average of however many iterations of the test. That would help give you an average.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> testList = CreateTestList();
            const string filter = "abc";

            TimeNewListMethod(FilterIntoNewListWithLinq, testList, filter);
            TimeInPlaceMethod(FilterInPlaceWithLinq, testList, filter);

            TimeNewListMethod(FilterIntoNewListWithForEach, testList, filter);

            TimeInPlaceMethod(FilterInPlaceWithRemoveAll, testList, filter);

            Console.Read();
        }

        public static void TimeInPlaceMethod(Action<List<string>, string> testMethod, List<string> toFilter, string filter)
        {
            List<string> toFilterCopy = new List<string>(toFilter);
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            testMethod(toFilterCopy, filter);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - time);
        }

        public static void TimeNewListMethod(Func<List<string>, string, List<string>> testMethod, List<string> toFilter, string filter)
        {
            List<string> toFilterCopy = new List<string>(toFilter);
            List<string> resultList;
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            resultList = testMethod(toFilterCopy, filter);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - time);
        }

        public static List<string> FilterIntoNewListWithLinq(List<string> toFilter, string filter)
        {
            return toFilter.Where(element => element.IndexOf(filter) > -1).ToList();
        }

        public static void FilterInPlaceWithLinq(List<string> toFilter, string filter)
        {
            toFilter = toFilter.Where(element => element.IndexOf(filter) > -1).ToList();
        }

        public static List<string> FilterIntoNewListWithForEach(List<string> toFilter, string filter)
        {
            List<string> returnList = new List<string>(toFilter.Count);
            foreach (string word in toFilter)
            {
                if (word.IndexOf(word[0]) > -1)
                {
                    returnList.Add(word);
                }
            }

            return returnList;
        }

        public static void FilterInPlaceWithRemoveAll(List<string> toFilter, string filter)
        {
            toFilter.RemoveAll(element => element.IndexOf(filter) == -1);
        }

        public static List<string> CreateTestList(int elements = 10000, int wordLength = 6)
        {
            List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
            StringBuilder nextWord = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < wordLength; j++)
                {
                    nextWord.Append(RandomCharacter());
                }
                returnList.Add(nextWord.ToString());
                nextWord.Clear();
            }

            return returnList;
        }

        public static char RandomCharacter()
        {
            return (char)('a' + rand.Next(0, 25));
        }

        public static Random rand = new Random();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole

> characters.IndexOf(word[0]) > -1

was a little unfamiliar to me and so I would go for something more readable and maintainable for future programmers.  It took me a minute to figure out you are checking the first char in each string in the list looking for a match in the range of { a A, B, C, a, b, c }.  It works, but to me, it was a little cryptic.  I'm starting having taken the time to read through it, but I would do it like this:

```
        foreach (string word in currentMatches)
        {               
            if (Regex.IsMatch(word, "^([A-Ca-c])"))
            {
                newMatches.Add(word);
            }
        }
```

I would not worry about copying the temp list back to the initial list.  You're already defined it filled it, go ahead and use it.